# How to enumerate enums when the enum type is only known at runtime?

Tags: c#, enums

I found this answer on stackoverflow to enumerate an enum of a certain type:

```
var values = (SomeType[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeType));
```

This works perfectly if i hard-code the enum type. But I need to be able to set the type in run time. i tried the following but this doesn't work:

```
var values = (typeof(T)[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
```

Comment: You mean you need to set it at run-time?

Comment: How do you mean: does not work? Does it not compile or does it show you an error during run time (and what error)?

Comment: "I found this answer on stackoverflow" - for the sake of giving credit, it is always adviseable to transform that respective text into a *link* to the answer you mention.

Comment: @Sjips visual studio shows a syntax error at Enum saying "; expected"

Comment: @user3340627: And did you add the semicolon, as suggested by that compiler error message? (Not that it would directly solve your problem, but that is an important error message to understand.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I have been trying out various solutions on stackoverflow for hours and I couldn't find the question i found this answer on again. I will make sure to add link to the question once i find it

Comment: You may be interested in [this post](http://www.codeducky.org/ins-outs-c-enums/), which describes how to do this as well as other common C# enum operations.

Comment: @ChaseMedallion The webpage is not available can you please post the link again ?

Comment: @user3340627 works fine for me. Give it another try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `T` is already of type `Type`. There is no need to use another `typeof`. A simple cast to a `T[]` should suffice:

```
T[] values = (T[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
```

Answer (score 1):

`typeof(T)` will generally return you a `Type` object, so compiler thinks you want to apply indexing to that object.

Try using:

`Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>()`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues<T>()
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
}
```

See [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GuoOda)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Cast<T>()` method for result custing and the `typeof(T).IsEnum` method for type checking (`T` must be an enumerated type).

The target method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues<T>()
{
  if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) 
    throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
  return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
}
```

Usage example:

```
public enum EnumFoo
{
  Foo1, Foo2
}
public enum EnumBar
{
  Bar1, Bar2
}
public void Main()
{
  foreach (var value in GetValues<EnumFoo>())
    Console.WriteLine(value); // Foo1 Foo2
  foreach (var value in GetValues<EnumBar>())
    Console.WriteLine(value); // Bar1 Bar2
}
```